# Selenium web driver, phpunit and Netbeans

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I need to automate websites made on php and for that my supervisor has suggested me to use webdriver with php as the programming language.
I'm using `Mac Os X 10.6.8.` I installed `mamp` to get `php` and then tried to install `Pear and phpunit`.
I successfully installed Pear using few commands on terminal and now I can see pear, peardev and phar.phar files in php5.5.3 -> bin

Then I somehow installed phpunit and now I can see `phpunit.phar` in `php5.5.3 -> bin`
Please tell me if the above mentioned things are enough to have phpunit working?
Also please help me install selenium webdriver for php and all the required libraries.
I'm new in automation. Step by step information will be really appreciable.

Thanks,
Ashalina

Answer (score 1):

[Installation](http://bx.com.au/blog/2012/08/selenium-and-phpunit-on-windows/)
Try this site, he explained everything in every single step how to install everything you need.

I'll copy paste it in here:

*Credits go to Steven George!*

Install Pear

NOTE: YOU CANT HAVE ANY SPACES IN YOUR PATH TO PHP AND PEAR.  THEREFORE, MAKE SURE PHP IS NOT INSTALLED IN THE “Program Files” DIRECTORY OTHERWISE YOU WILL NEVER GET PEAR WORKING FROM THE COMMAND LINE.

```
Download PEAR
Extract the archive using WinRAR
Create a “PEAR” directory in  C:\PHP
Copy the contents of the PEAR-x.x.x directory to the PEAR directory you just created
Download Console Getopt, Archive Tar, and Structures Graph
Create the directory c:\PHP\PEAR\Console.  Unzip and copy “Getopt.php” from the Console Getopt zip file into it.
Create the directory c:\PHP\PEAR\Archive. Unzip and copy “Tar.php” from the ArchiveTar zip file into it.
Create the directory c:\PHP\PEAR\Structures. Unzip and copy “Graph.php” and the contents of the “Graph” directory from the Structures Graph zip file into it.
Edit your php.ini and add your php PEAR directory to your include_path
Edit your system environment variables as follows:
    PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR = C:\PHP\PEAR\scripts\
    PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR = C:\PHP\PEAR\
    PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN = C:\PHP\php.exe
Add C:\PHP\PEAR\scripts to your “Path” environment variable
Run a command prompt as Administrator
cd to C:\PHP\PEAR\scripts
Create a pear.ini file in c:\Windows.  Alter the permissions so that any user can write to and modify it.
Run the following commands:
    pear config-set auto_discover 1
    pear config-set bin_dir c:\PHP\PEAR\scripts
```

Enable cURL

```
Copy php_curl.dll from the php “ext” directory to the Windows System32 directory
Edit php.ini and uncomment the line that references the cURL extension.
```

Install PHPUnit

```
You need to install specific versions of PHPUnit components if you are running Zend Framework 1.x (see: http://dustyreagan.com/downgrade-phpunit-3-6-to-3-5-15/).  From the administrative command prompt you opened earlier, run the commands:
    pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
    pear install --alldeps --force phpunit/PHPUnit
    pear install phpunit/DbUnit
    pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium
    pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Story
```

Install Java JRE

```
Download JRE
Install it as normal
```

Install Selenium

```
Download Selenium Server
Create a directory called “Selenium” in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
Copy the file you downloaded in step 1 into this directory.  It should be called “selenium-server-standalone-x.xx.x.jar”
Create a new MS batch file called Selenium.bat on your desktop.  Inside, type the command
    java -jar "c:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar” (note: Include the quotation marks and substitute the version number for the version you downloaded)
```

Download a PHP webdriver library

```
I like the Facebook one: https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver
```

Run Selenium

```
Execute the bat file you created for Selenium above.  This will lauch the selenium service that will listen for incoming commands from your test scripts.
```

You’re now ready to write PHPUnit tests using the PHP webdriver library. This library will talk to Selenium via the port that it opens (4444) when you run the batch file.